# Recover a file after empty Trash

Tags: 20.04, data-recovery, trash

How can I recover a file from Trash after I deleted it permanently from there?

I've tried many tools like "extundelete" and "foremost" but without success. If someone could give me step by step instructions I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: I'm not sure if you tried these steps in this post or not.  This source recommends a way to do it through using `lsof` and the pid https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101237/how-to-recover-files-i-deleted-now-by-running-rm#101247   If you tried this already the only other solution besides the one you mentioned is using `photorec`  There is also a link to a related question in that post as well which is here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/recovering-accidentally-deleted-files

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using your current system might overwrite the location you want restored so if you used your machine after deleting it it could be unrecoverable. Stop using the disk, use a live session to clone your partition and have [testdisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) pr [photorec](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) examine the partition.

Using testdisk is pretty [straightforward](https://www.tecmint.com/recover-deleted-files-using-testdisk-in-linux/) as it is fairly user friendly and suggests the likely option you need: pick a partition, set a filesystem (that will be ext4), and you let it scan. It will show a list and if the file is found you can make a copy.

[photorec](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step) is basically similar: select partition, filesystem and have it scan for files. When found restore file.

There is not much more to it... besides the one thing that is fatal: using the partition that the file was deleted from. If the location of the file is re-used no tool will be able to restore the file.